# Doctrine join one-to-many and hydrate collection

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a one-to-many relationship registered with Doctrine. When I run the DQL:

```
SELECT g FROM App\Models\Group g JOIN g.users u
```

I expect the Groups in the result to have the $users collection filled. However, this collection is empty, and when I access it Doctrine runs another query to hydrate it.

How can I fetch the Groups and their Users in one query? I have seen the fetch join option, but I don't like it, because then I have to recombine the groups and the users myself, which is difficult and messy.

Comment: when you call the results saved in the variable that gets the query, in the controller action or in the view, as I see it, it must be that you use it in the view, try this in your select, SELECT g, u

Comment: The problem then is it does a fetch join, so the result is an array of Groups *and* Users. But I want it to be just Groups, with the users property hydrated.

Answer (score 0):

Juan was right, I just needed to add `SELECT g, u`. The key thing for me was that this works:

```
SELECT g, u FROM App\Models\Group g JOIN g.users u
```

but this doesn't:

```
SELECT g, u FROM App\Models\Group g JOIN App\Models\Users u
```